# IDLE restarts when some of rpy2 modules are imported

Tags: python-idle, rpy2

i am quite novice with both Python and R, so I apologize in advance if i am asking something extremely obvious or stupid.

I downloaded rpy2-2.4.4.win-amd64-py3.4.exe from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs and installed rpy2. When I attempted to import rpy2.tests IDLE restarted. Same happens with all package content except rinterface and rlike.

I don't if it's relevant , but beforehand I tried installing rpy2 with pip and easy_install but it kept giving me errors ("TypeError: startswitch first arg must be bytes, not str" and "TypeError: 'PermissionError' object is not subscriptable" respectively).

Python 3.4
R 3.1.1

Thank you

```
>>> import rpy2
```

> > > import rpy2.interactive
> > >
> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >       import rpy2.ipython
> > >
> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >       import rpy2.rinterface
> > >
> > > import rpy2.rlike
> > >
> > > import rpy2.robjects
> > >
> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >       import rpy2.rpy_classic
> > >
> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >       import rpy2.tests
> > >
> > > ================================ RESTART ================================
> > >       import rpy2.tests_rpy_classic
> > >
> > > ================================ RESTART ================================

Comment: "Python 3.4 R 3.1.1" is ambiguous.  Are you running ancient 3.1.1 or recent 3.4.z?  Please retry with new 3.4.2.  If you got installation errors, then I do not expect the import to work.  Try import with regular console interpreter rather than Idle.  Then start Idle in command/console window with 'python -m idlelib' and you might see some error messages.  'RESTART' indicated that the user process stopped, but I am mystified since Idle usually catches all exceptions, even SystemExit.

Comment: Python versions was 3.4, R version 3.1.1. But I have also tried with python 3.3 and 2.7. I also tried couple of different R versions. I have tried importing from cmd but it just quits python when i import any of the same modules, exactly how the IDLE behaved. 
Thank you for answering!
Sorry for my late reply, I though I'll get an e-mail notification if someone replied